# After crash I get an unknown filesystem error

Tags: 14.04, boot, filesystem

Today my PC crashed (I was kinda expecting it cos Firefox and full screen videos kinda crash my PC) and when I rebooted I got an error saying unknown filesystem. 
I booted to a live USB and the ssd didn't show up in nautilus but when I went into the disks utility it was there but a couple of the partitions where unrecognised. I don't know what to do but I have this boot-repair log.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15403468/

Comment: Yours seems to be pretty old computer(Windows 95)...some issues with the boot partition of Windows 95 and also seems like hard drive h/w issues. Please test the h/w

Comment: Sorry the 40GB drive is an old backup drive from a laptop but I can do another boot repair without it in if you want. I tried unplugging it but the PC still didn't boot.